# Spring MVC, Thymeleaf & REST

Tags: java, android, rest, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I currently have a project using a Spring controller and Thymeleaf to create a little browser app.  The controller class is declared as

```
@Controller public class MyController {
```

Inside the controller I have a *GET* defined as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/foobars", method = RequestMethod.GET)
String index(Model model, --- more params ---) {
    //call repository and get foobarsList
    //model.addAttribute("foobars", foobarsList);
          ...
    return "foobars/foobarThymeleafTemplate"
}
```

The **call repository and get foobarList** is a call to a *MongoRepository* defined as:

```
public interface FoobarRepository extends MongoRepository< ... cut for brevity> {

    @RestResource(rel = "by-id") 
    Marker findMarkerById(String id);

    ... additional @RestResources cut for brevity ...
}
```

Again, the Browser App looks great. The *GET* calls the repository, populates the *model* with the list of foobars and Thymeleaf does it thing with that list.

**PROBLEM:** Now I need to access that same data from an *Android* App and I would prefer to use REST and just consume JSON in the Android App. I want to keep Thymeleaf but will refactor the browser app if necessary.

**QUESTION:** Is there a way to somehow use the same @Controller or will I have to maintain a second FoobarRestController using @RestController with /restFoobars endpoints?  The second REST controller works for sure but it seems kind of sloppy ... poor design.

Your thoughts and recommendations?

Thanks again.
-Rich

Answer (score 2):

My preferred approach here is to use inheritance:

```
@RequestMapping('/foobars')
abstract class FoobarBaseController {

    @RequestMapping
    abstract listAll()
}

@Controller
class FoobarHtmlController extends FoobarBaseController {
    @Override ModelAndView listAll() {
        new ModelAndView('foobars/foobarThymeleafTemplate', [foobars: foobarsList])
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping('/foobars', produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
class FoobarJsonController extends FoobarBaseController {
    @Override Collection<Foobar> listAll() {
        foobarsList
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if there's significant work to be done checking inputs or the like, you can implement that in the `BaseController` and have an `abstract listAllResponse(DomainObject foo)` that then returns the appropriate `ModelAndView` (HTML) or DTO (JSON).

The one pitfall of this approach is that you can't override just part of the `@RequestMapping`, so you do have to repeat the class's part of the mapping when you specify the `produces` parameter, but you can inherit the method-level mappings with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Expose Crud**

Use the `@Controller` to do the work of handling HTML page and using the Repository you can expose the entity via rest API for the basic actions like crud by using `SPRING-DATA-REST` to expose your entities. I think you are already doing it by looking at the code

```
 @RestResource(rel = "by-id") 
    Marker findMarkerById(String id);
```

**Expose Business logic**

If you want to expose any business logic, you have to create a `Service` layer and simply call it via your `@Controller` for the web page. and create another controller as `@RestController` for the web API interface.

*You may note, you are not duplicating any code here, as the logic is written at the single point in the Service layer. But using different controllers for different purposes.*

As you don't need all the logic in web page to get exposed to API, use of separate controller for REST may be a clean design implementation for your code if you can namespace your code as `app.web` and `app.api`.

**Food for thought**

Use a complete REST API implementation for web pages and android. Then use `AngualarJS` or `backboneJs` to do the client side implementation with HTML5. I think this is the future.

Comment: eventhough you answered this two years ago, and I agree using a complete  rest api for the back end and then using a javascript framework for the front end should logically be what the community should strive for, however there are still almost no questions on stackoverflow and still almost no documentations or tutorials on how to do this, either the Java community is very resistent to change, or this just doesn't work that well on the long run, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RestController for both Thymeleaf HTML and REST/JSON it seems.

The following works for me:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/projects")
public class ProjectController {

        /**
         * A REST reponse (JSON)
         * 
         * @param name
         * @return
         */
        @GetMapping(value = "/{name}")
        public Project get(@PathVariable String name) {
            return new Project(1l, name); 
        }

        /**
         * A thymeleaf HTML response
         */
        @GetMapping(value = "/hello.html")
        public String getAsHtml() {
            return "hello"; //name of the html file in src/main/resources/templates
        }
}
```

Comment: How can api `/hello.html` from above is going to return thymeleaf html?

Comment: It is the return statement that goes via thyme leaf. /hello.html is the URL it responds to.